# Excel - To calculate how many cell has value more than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to calculate in a row, how many cells have value more than 0.

I know this could be achieved with the formula =countif, but I couldn't figure out the right syntax for the criteria.

=COUNTIF(C2:L2, more than 1)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhzyr.png)

Comment: =COUNTIF(C2:L2, ">0")

Comment: Oh great, thanks, I'm very close. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enclose criteria by ""

```
=COUNTIF(C2:L2, ">=1")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the quotation marks around the condition. The manual says this:

```
 =COUNTIF(B2:B5,">55")
```